# Passing structs into function by address vs a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I was hoping someone could help me figure out why one version of the below code works, while the other doesn't. Below I've included the **initArray** method, stored in "worksheet.c". The function is accessed in main, both versions are given below.

```
void initArray(struct dynArray *a) {
    a->data = malloc(10 * TYPE_SIZE);
    assert(a->data != 0);
    a->size = 0;
    a->capacity = 10;   
}
```

This works. I create a dynArray struct and pass it to initArray by reference.

```
#include "worksheet0.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct dynArray b;
    initArray(&b);
    return 0;
}
```

This fails with a seg fault. I thought that passing `b` here would be the same as passing the struct by reference.

```
int main(void)
{
    struct dynArray *b = NULL;
    initArray(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you pass the value `NULL` to `void initArray(struct dynArray *a)` then `a->data` derefrences `NULL`.

Comment: If you wrote `struct dynArray *c = NULL; c->size = 0;` do you think that would work? (don't try it before answering)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the second case there is no memory allocated to which the struct pointer points to. It is simply a pointer having the value `NULL`. On your case by dereferencing the value `NULL` you have invoked *undefined behavior*.

It would work if you allocate memory, make changes to it and then return it's value. [But then you have to return the address of the allocated memory.] **OR** you can pass the address of the pointer variable and allocate memory to which dereferenced pointer (here the pointer has type `struct dynAray**`) would point to and make changes to it. 
Let's be more clear now slowly:

Why the first case works? You have a `struct dynArray` variable whose address you have passed into the function and then you have accessed the content of that address - wait! that means you have accessed the `struct dynArray` variable itself and made changes to its member variables. Yes that is what exactly happened in the first case.

In the second case, you have a pointer to `struct dynArray`. And then you passed it - de-referenced it. Where was it pointing to? Is it some `struct dynArray` variable's address that it contained? No. It was `NULL`. So it is wrong if you expect it to work.

The second would work - but you have to change things a bit! Let's see how:

```
struct dynArray* initArray() {
    struct dynArray* a = malloc(sizeof *a);
    assert(a != NULL);
    a->data = malloc(10 * TYPE_SIZE);
    assert(a->data != 0);
    a->size = 0;
    a->capacity = 10;
    return a;   
}
```

And in `main()`

```
struct dynArray* b;
b  = initArray();
```

You don't even need to pass the pointer variable. That would be meaningless if you want to do it like this.

And you know you can also pass the address of the pointer variable so that you can make changes to it -

```
void initArray(struct dynArray** a) {
    *a = malloc(sizeof **a);
    assert((*a) != NULL);
    (*a)->data = malloc(10 * TYPE_SIZE);
    assert((*a)->data != 0);
    (*a)->size = 0;
    (*a)->capacity = 10;  
}
```

For this in `main()` you would call it like this

```
struct dynArray* b;
initArray(&b);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example a pointer holding the address of an actual `struct` is passed to the function. But, in the second example the pointer `b` does not point to a `struct`. Instead, this pointer is initialized to `NULL`, and when this null pointer is dereferenced in the `initArray()` function, undefined behavior ensues.